# Why is converting an F# discriminated union to a string via string or ToString() so slow?

Tags: f#, f#-data

Is there a fast way to convert discriminated unions to strings?

I was trying to figure out why it was taking hours to save large collections of records to csv files using various methods. I tried CsvProvider.Save, sprintf, string builder, etc. and all were very slow. I think I have traced the problem to discriminated union type conversion.

My example below illustrates the problem. Is there a better way, or is my "manual conversion" the best option.

```ml
#time
open System

type Field = | Ying | Yang
let manual = function | Ying -> "Ying" | Yang -> "Yang"

// Discriminated Union versions

[for i = 0 to 100000 do yield (Ying).ToString()] |> ignore
//Real: 00:00:12.963, CPU: 00:00:13.281, GC gen0: 10, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

[for i = 0 to 100000 do yield (Ying) |> manual] |> ignore
//Real: 00:00:00.004, CPU: 00:00:00.015, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

// Others for comparison

[for i = 0 to 100000 do yield (1).ToString()] |> ignore
//Real: 00:00:00.011, CPU: 00:00:00.015, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
[for i = 0 to 100000 do yield (1.0).ToString()] |> ignore
//Real: 00:00:00.054, CPU: 00:00:00.062, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
[for i = 0 to 100000 do yield (1.0m).ToString()] |> ignore
//Real: 00:00:00.014, CPU: 00:00:00.015, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
```

Comment: Test1 is the desired result. The union type represents data, so when that data is changed in the source code I want it changed in the saved file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conversion to string is slow because the DU case name is really part of the code, not data for your program. Converting it into a string is effectively a meta-programming technique that has to reach outside of the normal runtime of the program, i.e. reflection in .NET.

Generally it's a good thing that an identifier name can't affect the running of your program, because it means that refactorings like renaming identifiers are completely safe.

However, if you really want to do this and make it fast, I think the most pragmatic solution is to use memoization:

```
let memoize fn =
    let cache = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<'a, 'b>()
    (fun x -> cache.GetOrAdd(x, fun _ -> fn x))

let showField : Field -> string = memoize string
```

The `memoize` function takes a function and creates a version of the function that caches the output for each input. The `showField` function should now be about as fast as your `manual` function after it has been run once for each DU case.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too picky about the format, maybe serializing the collection using NewtonSoft.Json would be faster.

Or you could try appending each DU value to a StringBuilder, and then call ToString on the StringBuilder to get the full string.